# Is it possible to prevent IE from displaying the "Submit Form" button over PDF forms?

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf

My organization wants to distribute fillable PDF forms, but the PDFs will not be submitted online or via email - they will be printed out. The idea is simply to cut down on handwritten forms. I know that Acrobat has a "typewriter" tool, but most of our end users probably do not know about this, and we want to take advantage of drop-down lists, etc.

When you open fillable forms in IE, a "Submit Form" button appears at the top of the page, even though the form cannot be submitted online. Clicking "Submit Form" doesn't do anything, and we're concerned that some of our end users will believe they are electronically submitting a form.

I've researched various methods that force PDFs to download, rather than open in the browser, but implementing those changes would be fairly intense considering that our network that has hundreds of PDFs scattered across hundreds of pages. We'd prefer a more simple solution.

**TL;DR: We want to distribute PDF forms that users can fill out and print, but we don't want the "Submit Form" button to appear in IE.**

Thanks!

Comment: Why not a Web Form and then have a Print option which prints presents the form in a Printable form?

Comment: You mean, instead of a PDF? That would require turning hundreds of PDFs into web forms.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that the *Submit Form* button was added at form creation. You might need to open the pdf using Adobe LiveCycle Designer and simply remove the button.

If you are using Adobe Acrobat Pro, go to `Forms>Edit Form` in Designer...